# Removing Special Character from console - c#

Tags: c#, console

I tried to write a function that remove special character from console..
Example, if I write:

```
Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
```

After I call the function with character 'o' , the console will be like:

```
"Hell Wrld"
```

I thought about running all over the console with

```
Console.SetCursorPosition(i,j);
```

but I can not get the value of "CursorPosition"..

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way for you to read what has already been written to the console.  One thing that you can do however is to provide your own output stream.  You could make your own `TextWriter` implementation that is given the original output stream along with the filter characters.  Then you can set the console's output stream to your new one, and after that anytime anyone writes to your programs output stream it will filter the character you choose.

I've run a few simple tests with the following lines of code, and it seems to be working just fine.  Let me know if it doesn't cover any more complex cases.

```
public class FilteringTextWriter : TextWriter
{
    private HashSet<char> invalidChars;
    private TextWriter destinationStream;
    public FilteringTextWriter(IEnumerable<char> invalidChars, TextWriter destinationStream)
        : base()
    {
        this.invalidChars = new HashSet<char>(invalidChars);
        this.destinationStream = destinationStream;
    }
    public override void Write(char value)
    {
        if (!invalidChars.Contains(value))
        {
            destinationStream.Write(value);
        }
    }
}
```

Elsewhere in Main or somewhere:

```
Console.SetOut(new FilteringTextWriter(new[] { 'o' }, Console.Out));
```

Answer (score 2):

You **CAN** read what has been written to the console!

There are no methods to read the console buffer in .NET, however there are couple WinAPI functions you can call to get the job done.

Check out [GetStdHandle()](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/GetStdHandle.html), [GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo()](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.getconsolescreenbufferinfo), and [ReadConsoleOutput()](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/ReadConsoleOutput.html)

Comment: Of course I meant there is no way in .NET framework to do it in. I know that you can do almost anything using the native API. And you can use the native API using Interop.

Answer (score 0):

[`Console.CursorLeft`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.cursorleft.aspx) and [`Console.CursorTop`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.cursortop.aspx) are the "get" methods for the cursor position.

Comment: And how do you read the character at the current cursor position?

Comment: Why the downvote? The OP's only actual question was how to get the value of CursorPosition. The OP referenced SetCursorPosition, so the question was about the position. I answered that question. Why is that worthy of a downvote? I understand that ultimately the OP wants the character... but that's not the part of the problem that was asked about.

Comment: You assume that the value of the cursor position is the index of it's position, OP clearly means the character at that position when he says "value".  The literal question itself is somewhat ambiguous, but the context of the question makes it clear that what he is really asking for is the character at a given position, not what the location of the cursor is.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot read from the Console buffer, i.e., you cannot get what has already been written to the console. (Directly in C# but you can do it with the native Windows API, or using Interop).

So, perhaps you'd better wrap the Console class in your own class, and filter the string before writing it to screen,

```
 public MyConsole
 {
     // expose the neede methods:
     public void WriteLine(string text)
     {
         Console.WriteLine(text.Replace(...)); // filter out the special chars
     }
 }
```

Then use `MyConsole` instead of `Console`.

Comment: This has several problems.  You have to change all of the code throughout the program to use the new writeline methods.  You have to write a lot of overloads to match all of the existing console write/writeline methods.  It can be very easily bypassed, either intentionally or accidentially, but using the regular `Console.Write` methods.

Comment: Having a better solution, as the provided in your answer, this is a hack. ;)